# SQL Insert in Stock from Purchase

Tags: sql, insert

I have two tables:

1. `Stock`

   ```
   Itemcode
   Itemname
   ```
2. `Purchase`

   ```
   Itemcode
   Itemname
   ```

I want to write some SQL to add all the new items from `Purchase` to `Stock` which do not yet exist in the `Stock` table.

Thanks

Comment: Why not try googling? It's clear.. You just need `Update` and `Not Exist`..

Comment: Please clarify your question by:
 - Specifying the db server (MySQL, PostrgreSQL, something else?) 
 - writing an example of current items in each table
 - writing the example of the rows you expect in the table after your query

This way people can give clear answers by demonstrating with a query you can run to get the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the `Item` and look if it exist in stock database, if it does `update the database` then if it doesn't, then `insert`it into `stock database`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? The key terms, if you want to research further, are an `INSERT` statement with a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause that calls a `correlated sub-query`.

```
INSERT Stock 
  (
    ItemCode, 
    ItemName
  )
SELECT
  p.ItemCode,
  p.ItemName
FROM
  Purchase AS p
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Stock AS s
    WHERE s.ItemCode = p.ItemCode
  )
```